# Why doesn't a Retain DeletionPolicy in CloudFormation preserve a changed DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to construct an `AWS::DynamoDB::Table` resource, and I have my `DeletionPolicy` set to `Retain`. Suppose I make a change to the `AttributeDefinitions` properties of this logical resource, such as renaming a hash key, and then perform a CloudFormation `update_stack`; such a change requires a 'replacement' of the resource. So far so good; I expect that the existing DynamoDB table is 'deleted' and a new one created in its place with the changed key definition.

However, I'm surprised that the original table is not 'left behind' as a result of the `DeletionPolicy`. Certainly, it would be possible to block the update entirely via a stack policy, but I was hoping that the DeletionPolicy would result in the now-defunct table being ejected from the CloudFormation stack and a new one arising in its place, but nonetheless not actually deleted.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is an expected behavior.

The `DeletionPolicy` is only applied when you actually **delete** the whole CloudFormation stack.

Source: [DeletionPolicy @ docs.aws.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html#:%7E:text=With%20the%20DeletionPolicy%20attribute%20you%20can%20preserve%2C%20and%20in%20some%20cases%2C%20backup%20a%20resource%20when%20its%20stack%20is%20deleted.)

If you want to keep your former DynamoDB tables during an **update**, you will need to back it up manually beforehand. You may use AWS Data Pipeline to backup your DynamoDB tables on Amazon S3.

Answer (score 7):

Use AWS attribute "UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain".